# How to put CSS style inside a php code?

Tags: php, html, css, edit

I want to edit the input boxes of table i.e. the fields where user inputs username and password in a table. I have created this table inside php code.

Now I want to make the input field texts in different color and only in small letters not caps.

I tried to give class for the td selected such as `class="smallCaps"` and tried to edit in the external css file but it didn't work.

```
<?php 
if ($username && $userid){
   echo "You have logged in as <b> $username </b>. Click here to <a href='logout.php'>         Logout </a>";  
 }
  else {
 $form = "<form action= 'index.php' method='POST'> 
 <table> 
    <tr> <td> <font color='black' face='arial' size='3'>Username:  </font> </font></td>    <td> <input type='text' name='user' placeholder='Username' > </td>
    <td> <font color='black' face='arial' size='3'>Password: </td>  </font><td> <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'></td> 
    <td> <button type='submit' class='btn' name='loginbtn' value ='Login'><font size='3'>Login</font> </td></button>
    <tr><td> <a href='signup.php'> <font color='black' face='arial' size='3'>Register</font> </a> </td> </tr>
  </table>
   </form>";
```

Comment: Please don't use `<font>` anymore, it's deprecated. Use CSS instead. In HTML5, this tag isn't even supported anymore.

About the 'figuring out what class your `td` has': Just inspect the element with your browser and look if the class was assigned correctly. If it is, PHP is working fine and the problem is merely a broken CSS rule or something.

Which class(es) does your browser assign to the `td`s?

Comment: can you please post your code in fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing here. Did you include the external css file?

And I assume you did [ class='smallCaps' ] not [ class="smallCaps" ] which would conflict echo.

Answer (score 0):

you should try inline styling like that:

```
<table style=" background-repeat:no-repeat; width:450px;margin:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr style="height:40px; width:450px; margin:0;">
    <td style="height:40px; width:40px; margin:0;">
```

etc....

Comment: You really shouldn't have structure and design intertwined. Don't mix your HTML with CSS with the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your client side and your server side codes separately. You can do so by doing the following:

```
echo '<table class="myClass">';
```

and then go put the table styles in the class you declared

```
.myClass{
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
 }
```